# How to integrate a function of r that contains the first derivative of r in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, sympy, calculus

I have to integrate a function over a variable that contains the derivative of this variable.

I'm using jupyter and here is my code:

```
from sympy import *
m, p, g, a, t=symbols('m, p, g, a, t')
r=Function('r')
integrate((r*(p**2/(m**2*r**4)-2*a*g)-r(t).diff(t)**2*4*a**2*r)/(1+4*a**2*r**2),r)
```

`r(t).diff(t)` is my clumsy way of attempting to write `\dot{r}`.

I get the following error :

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'UndefinedFunction' and 'int'

Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have `r(t)` instead of `r`. Try the following: `integrate((r(t)*(p**2/(m**2*r(t)**4)-2*a*g)-r(t).diff(t)**2*4*a**2*r(t))/(1+4*a**2*r(t)**2), r(t))`